# How to remove outline border from input button

Tags: css, button

When I click somewhere else the border disappears, I tried to use `onfocus: none`, but that didn't help. How to make this ugly button border disappear when I click on it?

```css
input[type=button] {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Example Button">
```

Comment: looks fine on my mozilla browser

Comment: The focus rectangle is supposed to help the user observe that the click was effective and thereby prevent him from accidentally clicking twice. So are you sure you are solving a problem and not creating one?

Comment: A good read http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

Answer (score 315):

Using `outline: none;` you can remove that border in chrome.

```
<style>
input[type=button] {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: On Chrome, I had to add `outline: none;` rule to `input[type="button"]:focus` rather than `input[type="button"]`.

Comment: Works in Microsoft Edge too

Answer (score 103):

Focus outline in Chrome and FF:

[image: Remove Chrome button outline in CSS] [image: Remove Firefox button outline in CSS]

**removed button focus outline**:

[image: Button without outline in CSS]

```css
button,
input[type=button] {
  outline: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

/*
  Accessibility (A11Y)
  Don't forget! User accessibility is important
*/
button:focus,
input[type=button]:focus {
  /* your custom focused styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 93):

It works for me simply :)

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, but how would you do it without !important? I've heard from a lot of sources that you should only use it only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I did this button styling for whole application in external css. If u want ignore it u can do it with #id in css using that in each button:
#button-tyle{
outline: 0;
}

or use same style for all buttons without #id in each button, here is a demo [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/OR7kviKn4XMnd9jQ4wvS?p=preview):
input[type="button"]
{
width:70px;
height:30px;
margin-left:72px;
margin-top:15px;
display:block;
background-color:gray;
color:white;
border: none;
outline: 0;
}

Comment: To remove blue background color onclick i added -> *{ -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important; }

Comment: This worked first time perfectly - Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

Set both the `outline` and the `box-shadow` properties of the button to `none` and make them **important**.

```css
input[type=button] {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

The reason for setting the values to **important** is that, if you are using other CSS libraries or frameworks like Bootstrap, it might get overridden.

Comment: The `box-shadow` works for me on Edge, nice : )

Answer (score 34):

This one worked for me

```
button:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

The `outline` property is what you need. It's shorthand for setting each of the following properties in a single declaration:

- `outline-style`
- `outline-width`
- `outline-color`

You could use `outline: none;`, which is suggested in the accepted answer. You could also be more specific if you wanted:

```
button {
    outline-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
button:focus{outline:none !important;}
```

add `!important` if it is used in **Bootstrap**

Comment: I think the asker already tried this, after all, the question says `tried onfocus none, but didn't help`.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the problem caused when you change the outline property on a focus, is to give a visual effect when the user Tab on the input button or click on it.

In this case is a submit type, but you can apply to a type="button" too.

```css
input[type=submit]:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    background-color: rgb(208, 192, 74);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the html below:

```
<button class="btn-without-border"> Submit </button>
```

In the css style do the following:

```
.btn-without-border:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

This code will remove button border and will disable button border focus when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

As many others have mentioned, `selector:focus {outline: none;}` will remove that border **but** that border is a key accessibility feature that allows for keyboard users to find the button and *shouldn't* be removed.

Since your concern seems to be an aesthetic one, you should know that you can change the color, style, and width of the outline, making it fit into your site styling better.

```
selector:focus {
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-color: red;
}
```

Shorthand:

```
selector:focus {
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's greatly simple than you think. When the button is focussed, apply the `outline` property, like this:

```
button:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

But when I use `none` value, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Removing nessorry accessible event not a good idea in up to standard web developments.
either way if you looking for a solution removing just the outline doesn't solve the problem. you also have to remove the blue color shadow. for specific scenarios use a separate class name to isolate the this special style to your button.

```
.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
}
```

Better do this

```
.remove-border.focus, .remove-border:focus {
        outline: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the outline is an accessibility nightmare. People tabbing using keyboards will never know what item they're on.

Best to leave it, as most clicked buttons will take you somewhere anyway, or if you HAVE to remove the outline then isolate it a specific class name.

```
.no-outline {
  outline: none;
}
```

Then you can apply that class whenever you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to restore outline when using the keyboard is to use `:focus-visible`. However, this doesn't work on IE :https://caniuse.com/?search=focus-visible.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome and Mozilla added this line not only around buttons but also around linked text, I use on my site this:

```
a:focus {outline: none;
}
```

Works for both browsers, links, and buttons.

Btw, this did not (27.4.2021):

```
input[type=button]{
   outline:none;
}
input[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner {
   border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's also good note that `outline: none` can be applied to both `<button>` tags and `input[type=button]` to remove the browser-applied border on click.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below css:

```css
.btn {
  border: none !important;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Try with this, you have to make

```css
border: none !important
```