# How to hide button outline

Tags: css

I have this page with a lot of buttons here: https://jsfiddle.net/Android272/c150305z/

I have tried every combination of the below code but nothing will get rid of the outline.

```
*:focus,
button,
button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: 0;
  outline-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  outline-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance mean to use `border: none`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19886893/383904

Comment: Please see my answer below. Some people are saying that the outline is the problem but obviously not because you overwrote the outline properties. It is definitely a 1px border that is applied by twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, one could write:

```
button {
    outline: none; 
}
```

This will remove the select border from a button. However, in this case we require `!important` on the outline property to prevent Bootstrap from overwriting it (seen below). I would also recommend adding cross-browser support for a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886843/how-to-remove-outline-border-from-input-button/19886893#19886893) with Chrome and Firefox.

```
button {
    outline: none !important; 
}

input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, Bootstrap has these styles associated with buttons on focus that you need to either remove or overwrite.

```
.btn.active.focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Use this to overwrite it:

```
.btn.active.focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated your fiddle here:
[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c150305z/15/)

just this line: 
`button {
  outline: none !important; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is using twitter bootstrap's `btn` and`btn-primary` clasess

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary circle"...></button>
```

This is what those classes do:

```
 .btn{
     border: 1px solid transparent;
 }

.btn-primary {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #337ab7;
      border-color: #2e6da4;
 }
```

So use `border: none;` and that annoying blue border shall disappear!

https://jsfiddle.net/c150305z/16/