# Getting a border around my icon when it is set to active by default

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML, CSS, javascript. I tried to set a link active by default.
but I am getting a problem of having a border around my 'icon of the link' when it is first loaded.

**I haven't at least 10 reputations for attaching an Image**

So I am giving the link explicitly [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wuYBzlOIchq-KCJjjrTLzXs7xSnTTApv)

Actually, I wanted to set this div to look as active when it is loaded. So I took the help of Javascript for making the 'link with an icon in that div' to set as active by default. But I wasn't able to change the color of the complete div when the HTML page is first loaded. So I again took the help of Javascript and get success another time. But I am facing a problem right now, which is, I am getting a border around that Icon of Link.

Here goes the code-

HTML-

```
<div class="row hnss m-0 p-0">
<div class="col-3 p-0" id="tabDivs1"><a class="tabClick" id="tabLinks1" href="#" onmousedown="colorTheSelected1()" ><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></div>
<div class="col-3 p-0" id="tabDivs2"><a class="tabClick" id="tabLinks2"  href="#" onmousedown="colorTheSelected2()"><i class="fas fa-bell fa-2x"></i></a></i></div>
<div class="col-3 p-0" id="tabDivs3"><a class="tabClick" id="tabLinks3"  href="#" onmousedown="colorTheSelected3()"><i class="fas fa-search fa-2x"></i></a></i></div>
<div class="col-3 p-0" id="tabDivs4"><a class="tabClick" id="tabLinks4"  href="#" onmousedown="colorTheSelected4()"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-2x"></a></i></div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.hnss div a
{
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
position:absolute;
color: #fafafa;

}

.hnss div a:focus
{
background-color: #4fc3f7;
color:white;
}
/*I have trid the below code, but it didn't work*/
.hnss div a i 
{
border:none;
}
```

Javascript-

```
var checkIt = document.getElementById("tabLinks1").focus();


// Just For Giving My work a try, I used The Below code
document.getElementById('tabLinks1').style.border="0"


document.getElementById("tabDivs1").style.backgroundColor="#4fc3f7"
```

Comment: In the given link of the photograph, the icon of "Home" has a border around it.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to figure out where that border (or outline) comes from, so that you know what exactly you need to overwrite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Remove Outline Border From Input Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886843/how-to-remove-outline-border-from-input-button)

Comment: Does the answer I put below solve the problem?

Comment: Removing the default browser style for active elements is a bad practice regarding accessibility. Users need to get cues of which element is currently active.

Comment: @Wowsk yes dude, Thanks a  lot, you are great, it solved my problem in One second. I am really grateful for your help

Comment: @MoaazBhnas thanks for your advice, I will keep it remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css:

```
.hnss div a:focus, .hnss div a:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

or

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/

Comment: dude, You are the Great. You solved my problem in One Second.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for their contribution and help, I am really grateful for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.hnss div a i {
   outline:none;
}
.hnss div a i ::-moz-focus-inner {
   border: 0;
}
```

This covers both Chrome and Firefox.

More information can be seen: [How To Remove Outline Border From Input Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886843/how-to-remove-outline-border-from-input-button)