# How to remove the yellow highlight when html button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I want to remove the yellow box which appears when an HTML button Is clicked in smartphone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Remove Outline Border From Input Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886843/how-to-remove-outline-border-from-input-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the outline method to get your desired working.

```
<style>
input[type="button"]
{
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:35px;
    display:block;
    background-color:gray;
    color:white;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
}
</style>
```