# Removing blue border around BlueprintJS numeric input on focus

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, sass, blueprintjs

I'm using a BlueprintJS Numeric Input component and want to remove the blue outline when you focus on the component. I want to remove it because it's inside something else that has its own border when you focus it. I've built the following example:

```
// Numeric input

const input = (
  <Blueprint.Core.NumericInput
  className={"inputTest"}
  value={1}
  buttonPosition={"none"}
  />);
```

```
// styling.scss

.inputTest {
  width: 50px;
  
  * > * {
    :focus {
      border: none;
    }
  }
}
```

But when you click on the input, it still has a blue border. Is there some other way to remove this?

https://jsfiddle.net/wbdfxrgz/8/

Comment: You need to replace the box-shadow and not the border.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove outline border from input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886843/how-to-remove-outline-border-from-input-button)

Comment: @m4n0 that did not fix the issue, there is still the border.

Comment: @xdumaine I already looked at that, none of the answers worked on this.

Comment: Check this: https://nimb.ws/Uhz9dW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is bad:

`* > *` means "the immediate child of any child" and a nested `:focus` is *another* child but the input isn't nested that deep. Additionally, you need to override box-shadow:

```css
.inputTest {
  width: 50px;
  
  input:focus {
      // default active state box shadow
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(19, 124, 189, 0), 0 0 0 0 rgba(19, 124, 189, 0), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.15), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.2);;
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9uLjwyf/