# Disable Click Feedback React Typescript

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I try to disable the touch feedback in my Smartphone Browser (Safari and DuckDuckGo) for a rendered div.
I also tried to use a button, but i got the same output.
I´m using typescript and react 18.2.0

**.tsx file:**

```
return (
        <div className='gallerySliderLeft' onClick={props.showNextImage}> {'left'}</div>
        <div className='gallerySliderRight' onClick={props.showNextImage}> {'right'}</div>
);
```

**The CSS:**

```
.gallerySliderRight {
  margin-top: 1vh;
  transition: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
.gallerySliderLeft{
  margin-top: 1vh;
  transition: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
```

The CSS is correct applied and there is no parent element which changes the CSS or similar.

Is there any other styling I can try ?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove outline border from input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886843/how-to-remove-outline-border-from-input-button)

Comment: sadly not.. but thank you!!